# ¿Cómo puedo evitar que se genere un pedido en una pasarela de pagos personalizada?

Tags: php, woocommerce

mi problema es el siguiente he creado una pasarela de pagos personalizada y a pesar de que el banco procesa o no procesa el pago igualmente en woocommerce me crea el pedido y le asigna como pendiente de pago, lo que yo quiero hacer es lo siguiente: si el pago no fue aprobado por diversos motivos por ejemplo; el numero de tarjeta errado, que no se genere el pedido y si fue aprobado que se genere el pedido.

El código que tengo hasta ahora es el siguiente:

```
**if ($err) {
    
                wc_add_notice( __('Ha habido un error en la API', 'woocommerce-paymercantil'), 'error' );
                return;
            } else {
            
               if (isset($response1->error_list)) {
                        wc_add_notice( __($response1->error_list[0]->description, 'woocommerce-payment'), 'error' );
                        return;
               }else{
            
                     // we received the payment
                    $order->payment_complete();
                    $order->reduce_order_stock();
                
                
                    // Empty cart
                    $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
                
                    // Redirect to the thank you page
                
                    return array(
                        'result' => 'success',
                        'redirect' => $this->get_return_url( $order )
                    );
               }**
```

muchas gracias por lo que me puedan ayudar

Comment: Y ese código está dentro de una función que se ejecuta con algún hook o filtro de woocommerce? o está inyectado en el código de la plantilla?

Comment: si, esta dentro de la función process_payment

Comment: public function process_payment( $order_id ) {
 global $woocommerce;
            $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
                  $url = $this->endpoint_pay;
                    $result = $this->api_curl_request_debito($payload, $url);
                    $response1 = json_decode($result);

Answer (score 0):

Ya que nadie me pudo ayudar lo que hice que me funcionó fue agregar esta línea de código.

wp_delete_post($order_id,true);

al momento de que el banco devuelve un error.